# Compare equal length lists to find positions that share the same element

Tags: python, list, element

I want to compare a list of lists that have the same length, but differ in their content. My script should return only the **positions** that share exactly the same element (in all lists).
For example:

l = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,8,8,4,3,4,5,7,8],[5,6,7,4,9,9,9,8],[0,0,1,4,7,6,3,8]]

and as a result I get a list of positions p = [3,7] as in all list we have '4' and '8' at positions 3 and 7, respectively.

These elements can be strings as well, I'm just giving an example with integers. Thanks for any help!

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,8,8,4,3,4,5,7,8],[5,6,7,4,9,9,9,8],[0,0,1,4,7,6,3,8]]

p = [i for i, j in enumerate(zip(*l)) if all(j[0]==k for k in j[1:])]

# p == [3] - because of some typo in your original list, probably too many elements in the second list.
```

This is just the one-liner (list comprehension) version of this, more verbose:

```
p = []
for i, j in enumerate(zip(*l)):
    if all(j[0]==k for k in j[1:]):
        p.append(i)
```

`zip(*l)` gives you:

```
[(1, 9, 5, 0),
 (2, 8, 6, 0),
 (3, 8, 7, 1),
 (4, 4, 4, 4),
 (5, 3, 9, 7),
 (6, 4, 9, 6),
 (7, 5, 9, 3),
 (8, 7, 8, 8)]
```

`enumerate()` puts numbers 0, 1, 2, ... to each tuple within that list.

`all(j[0]==k for k in j[1:])` compares the first element of the tuple with all remaining elements and returns `True` if all of them are equal, `False` otherwise (it returns `False` as soon as it finds a different element, so it's faster)

Comment: It is ``p = [`` **j[0]** ``for i, j in enumerate(zip(*l)) if ....`` , not ``p = [i for i, j in ....``

Answer (score 2):

I liked eumiro solution, but I did with a set

```
p = [i for i, j in enumerate(zip(*l)) if len(set(j)) == 1]
```

Comment: +1, wow I was so busy with the `all()` solution, that I forgot about `set()` totally. Although this is slower than my solution (my test stops as soon as one element does not match), it looks awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,8,8,4,3,4,5,7,8],[5,6,7,4,9,9,9,8],[0,0,1,4,7,6,3,8]]
r = []

for i in range(len(l[0])):
    e = l[0][i]
    same = True
    for j in range(1, len(l)):
        if e != l[j][i]:
            same = False
            break
    if same:
        r.append(i)

print r
```

prints only [3], as l[1] does not have 8 at position 7. It have one more element.

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,8,8,4,3,6,5,8],[5,6,7,4,9,9,9,8],[0,0,1,4,7,6,3,8]]

first = li[0]
r = range(len(first))
for current in li[1:]:
    r = [ i for i in r if current[i]==first[i]]

print [first[i] for i in r]
```

result

```
[4, 8]
```

.

Comparing execution's times:

```
from time import clock

li = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
      [9,8,8,4,5,6,5,8,9,13],
      [5,6,7,4,9,9,9,8,9,12],
      [0,0,1,4,7,6,3,8,9,5]]

n = 10000

te = clock()
for turn in xrange(n):
    first = li[0]
    r = range(len(first))
    for current in li[1:]:
        r = [ i for i in r if current[i]==first[i]]
    x = [first[i] for i in r]
t1 = clock()-te
print 't1 =',t1
print x


te = clock()
for turn in xrange(n):
    y = [j[0] for i, j in enumerate(zip(*li)) if all(j[0]==k for k in j[1:])] 
t2 = clock()-te
print 't2 =',t2
print y

print 't2/t1 =',t2/t1
print
```

result

```
t1 = 0.176347273187
[4, 8, 9]
t2 = 0.579408755442
[4, 8, 9]
t2/t1 = 3.28561221827
```

.

With

```
li = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,2,22,26,24,25],
      [9,8,8,4,5,6,5,8,9,13,18,12,15,14,15,15,4,16,19,20,2,158,35,24,13],
      [5,6,7,4,9,9,9,8,9,12,45,12,4,19,15,20,24,18,19,20,2,58,23,24,25],
      [0,0,1,4,7,6,3,8,9,5,12,12,12,15,15,15,5,3,14,20,9,18,28,24,14]]
```

result

```
t1 = 0.343173188632
[4, 8, 9, 12, 15, 20, 24]
t2 = 1.21259110432
[4, 8, 9, 12, 15, 20, 24]
t2/t1 = 3.53346690385
```